# How to get coverage for anonymous class overridden methods using junit mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have below code to retry the request based on response code.

```
public class Sample {
    public static HttpClient getInstance() {
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom();     
            builder.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {
                int waitPeriod = 200;

                @Override
                public boolean retryRequest(final HttpResponse response, final int executionCount,
                    final HttpContext context) {

                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    return ((statusCode == 429)&& (executionCount < 3));
                }

                @Override
                public long getRetryInterval() {
                    return waitPeriod;
                }
            });

        return builder.build();

    }
}
```

While I am writing the unit tests for this `getInstance` method the overridden methods `(retryRequest, getRetryInterval)` are not getting covered. How can I write the unit tests to get coverage for these methods as well.
By googling I found we can use `ArgumentCaptor`.
I have tried the below code, but it does not work.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context.xml"})
@PrepareForTest({ HttpClients.class, Sample.class})
public class Sample {

    @Mock
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilderMock;

    @Mock
    CloseableHttpClient clientMock;

    @Mock
    HttpResponse responseMock;

    @Mock
    HttpContext contextMock;

    @Mock
    StatusLine statusLineMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(HttpClients.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {       
        when(HttpClients.custom()).thenReturn(clientBuilderMock);
        when(clientBuilderMock.build()).thenReturn(clientMock);
        when(responseMock.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLineMock);
        when(statusLineMock.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(429);

        Sample.getInstance();

        ArgumentCaptor<ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy.class);
        verify(clientBuilderMock).setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(argumentCaptor.capture());
        ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy retryStrategy = argumentCaptor.getValue();
        retryStrategy.retryRequest(responseMock, 3, contextMock);       
    }

}
```

`argumentCaptor.capture()` is always giving me `null`.I am getting like

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
>   No argument value was captured!
>   You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...
>   ...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called.
>    Can anyone help me on this. I would like to test the retryRequest method functionality.

Comment: Do you use PowerMock? Mockito can't mock static methods like `HtppClients.custom()`.

Comment: Yes I use PowerMock to mock static methods.

Comment: Can you post an [mre] that shows the complete UnitTest? When I tried to test it, I didn't run in any particular problem, so its likely that your missing something in your test class.

Comment: I have edited my original question by providing complete unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** rephrased the answer to make it easier to read.

---

1. Classes that are supposed to be handeled by PowerMockito need to be 
   declared in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.
2. If annotations are used to create the mocks all annotated classes which are not declared in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation, are created by Mockito.
3. If annotations are used to create the mocks and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is called,
   this apparently causes the declaration to be overriden and all mocks are created by Mockito instead.
   (Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/yPBey4hr7IU)
4. Mockito can not handle static or final methods.
    The mocking operation might fail silently.

---

The root of your problem is that `HttpClientBuilder#setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` is a 
final method and therefore can not be handeled by Mockito.

The solution is that the Mock of `HttpClientBulder` has to be handeled by PowerMockito.
In accordance with `1.` it needs to be declared in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

```
@PrepareForTest({ HttpClients.class, HttpClientBuilder.class, Sample.class})
```

If you want to use Annotations to create the mocks, you **must not** call

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

(see `2.` / I verified this issue with the latest powermockito versions (1.7.4 / 2.0.2))

Else you have to create the mock manually.

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilderMock = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClientBuilder.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation. It is working. For testing retryRequest() for 3 times I am calling this method inside for loop. Is it a good practice to write like this in unit tests?

Comment: Probably not. Moving the anonymous class to its own file and testing that instead is probably the cleaner way to this. You don't really need a loop in that case as you can freely controll your parameters. Also consider writing an Integration test.